# Limit linux process memory

Tags: linux, memory, limit

I have a c++ program running on Linux, and I would like to limit the amount of physical memory that this program can use, to force it to make a lot of page swaps.

Anyone know of a good way of doing this?

I have already tried with ulimit -m [limit in KB] and setrlimit(RLIMIT_RSS, &limit), but they didn't have any effect.

Comment: There is an answer to this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983120/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process which will probably help you.

Comment: Did you look into [cgroups memory controller](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/memory.txt)? (I've never looked into it, so don't know if it could be used, but looks promising)